# Связать 2 поля со списком

Tags: php

Имеется следующая функция, которая отображает форму в которой есть 2 поля со списком с данными из таблицы с иерархией. Как мне сделать эти 2 поля со списком зависимыми, чтобы при выборе значение в первом поле, во втором поле отображались соответствующие.

```
function input_recipe() {
    // Создаём выпадающий список 1
    $dropDown = '<select name="cat_name">';
    $query = mysql_query('select * from category where level = 1');
    if (mysql_num_rows($query)) {
        while ($cat = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $dropDown .= sprintf(
                    '<option value="%s">%s</option>', $cat["id_category"], $cat["name"]
            );
        }
    }

$dropDown .= '</select>';

// Создаём выпадающий список 2
$dropDown2 = '<select name="cat2_name">';
$query = mysql_query('select * from category where level = 2');
if (mysql_num_rows($query)) {
    while ($cat = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $dropDown2 .= sprintf(
                '<option value="%s">%s</option>', $cat["id_category"], $cat["name"]
        );
    }
}

$dropDown2 .= '</select>';

// Вставляем их в форму.
$txt = sprintf("<form method='post'><table>
        <tr>
          <td style='text-align: center; font-weight: bold;'>Категория</td>
          <td style='text-align: center; font-weight: bold;'>Категория</td>
          <td style='text-align: center; font-weight: bold;'>Название</td>
          <td style='text-align: center; font-weight: bold;'>Описание</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>%s</td><td>%s</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='recipe_name' id='recipe_name'></td>
          <td><input type='text' name='recipe_description' id='recipe_description'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan='4' style='text-align: center'><input type='submit' value='Добавить запись'></td>
          </tr>
    </table></form>", $dropDown, $dropDown2
);
return $txt;
}
```

Comment: Начать использовать javascript

Comment: Ну по логике, кол-во записей должны совпадать в обеих таблицах, что бы не было путаницы.
И отгда можно будет выводить в 2х циклах.

А если кол-во записей разное, то привязывать одну таблицу  к другой по айдишнику к примеру, и выводить записи проверяя по ид.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы это все работало без постоянной перезагрузки страницы после каждого выбора, Вам необходимо использовать JavaScript и ajax. Идея такая: в JavaScript вешаете обработчик на изменение значения поля первого списка, по изменению значения в первом выпадающем списке отправляете ajax запрос, передавая идентификатор выбраной категории, по которому выполняется php скрипт, который вернет соответствующие позиции для второго списка, по успешной отработке ajax, обновляете содержимое DOM элемента второго списка, заполняя его полученными позициями. Пример тривиальный, так что советую вбить в поисковик "*javascript ajax*", "*jquery ajax*" и разобраться с технологией (это можно сделать минут за 40 для быстрого старта, но научиться действительно грамотно все использовать и писать понятный и поддерживаемый js код, без использования каких-либо фреймворков - это уже задача не из легких, приходит только с опытом и то не ко всем, многих упомянутый выше "быстрый старт" расслабляет и навсегда оставляет на уровне быдлокода).

Если же пытаться сделать все на PHP, то, как я уже сказал, нужно смириться с необходимостью перезагрузки страницы, после каждой смены категории. Например добавить кнопку "Открыть категорию", которая относилась бы к той же форме, к которой и первый выпадающий список. По нажатию на эту кнопку отправлять запрос (`GET` или `POST`, не так важно) на эту же самую страницу, в котором передавать идентификатор выбраной категории. В скрипт добавить  проверку, что если пришел на вход переданный идентификатор, тогда формировать второй выпадающий список, передавая в SQL запрос для выборки полученный идентификатор, и таким образом собирать только соответствующие пункты.